# net core api newtonsoft.json Self referencing loop detected for property 'Client' with type 'Microsoft.Graph.GraphServiceClient'. Path 'Invitations'

Tags: asp.net-core, json.net, microsoft-graph-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I am storing GraphServiceClient in the session (because I need to use it in other Requests):

```
HttpContext.Session.SetObject("graphClient", _graphServiceClient);
```

GraphServiceClient is an Object, so I extended Session:

```
public static class SessionExtensions
    {
        public static void SetObject(this ISession session, string key, object value)
        {
            session.SetString(key, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value));
        }

        public static T GetObject<T>(this ISession session, string key)
        {
            var value = session.GetString(key);
            return value == null ? default(T) : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(value);
        }
    }
```

When trying Post request I get the following Error with 401 Status

> "Self referencing loop detected for property 'Client' with type
> 'Microsoft.Graph.GraphServiceClient'. Path 'Invitations'."

Comment: To be able to reproduce your issue, we'll need to see the code and payload that is causing the issue. BR

Comment: Why are you attempting to store the client instead of just the token(s)? You should only need to store the token and then create a client when needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Marc LaFleur suggested, I solved this issue by storing the token